# exclude dates greater than 500 years old in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a column with dates. Some of the dates are missing (empty) and a few dates are in the year 1500.

I want to get only those rows where either the date is within the last 10 years or is missing.

Since Pandas has an time range of 584 years, I do this to avoid raising an error:

```
import arrow as ar
import pandas as pd

df[(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors = 'coerce') >= ar.utcnow().shift(days=-3650).date())]
```

However, this also gets rid of the rows which have missing date and I do not want that. Is there a way to exclude dates > 10 years old but not the missing dates for this dataframe which also has dates > 500 years old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just add the conditions

```
con1=(pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors = 'coerce') >= ar.utcnow().shift(days=-3650).date())
con2=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors = 'coerce').isnull()

df.loc[con1|con2]
```